# Image associated/file with multimedia type

Tags: multimedia

After creating a multimedia type in Tridion "`System Administration`" and uploading an image for that MM type, how can I locate that physical file in Tridion to display in my TBB?

Answer (score 5):

A multimedia type is just a definition of a type of binary file you want to handle in Tridion, it's not a piece of content you can use.

You're still missing the following 2 steps:

1. Create or modify an existing Multimedia Schema that allows editors to create content with this new Multimedia Type
2. Create a new Multimedia Component - here you can upload a binary of that type